# android Video App: send notification to every app user when i add new video to server

Tags: android, api, video, push-notification, server

I have an android Video app, now I want to send Notifications to each user whenever i add a new Video on my Server, here is the latest Video API from my Server [http://flazzin.com//api.php?latest][1]  [1]: http://flazzin.com//api.php?latest
I have a cPanel access to but don't really know how can i send push notifications to each user when i upload a new video on server. Kindly Guide me. I have explored about Firebase and One Signal but can't understand how can i integrate that Video Factor with them, because they have there own servers for this i think.

Answer (score 0):

Follow [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client?authuser=0) url to properly integrate FCM. Save fcm registration token in your server database while user uses the app.

Call the below function while adding a new video

```
public function sendTaskNotification(){
    $registrationIds = get_all_fcm_tokes(); // Select all saved fcm registration tokens
    if(count($registrationIds) > 0){
        $fcmApiKey = 'YOUR FCM API Key';
        $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';//Google URL

        $message = "New video availiable";//Message which you want to send
        $title = 'Title';

        // prepare the bundle
        $msg = array('body' => $message,'title' => $title, 'sound' => 'default');
        $fields = array('registration_ids' => $registrationIds,'data' => $msg);

        $headers = array(
            'Authorization: key=' . $fcmApiKey,
            'Content-Type: application/json'
        );

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url );
        curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
        curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
        curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
        curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
        curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
        $result = curl_exec($ch );
        if ($result === FALSE) {
            die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
        }
        curl_close($ch);    
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Add this class to your android project

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
        String message = remoteMessage.getData().get("body");
        String title = remoteMessage.getData().get("title");
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                        .setContentTitle(title)
                        .setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://com.deirki.ffm/" + R.raw.ffmsound))
                        .setContentText(message);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

        // Add as notification
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        manager.notify(0, builder.build());
    }

}
```

Add the above service to manifest

```
        <service android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```